# More concise '&&' operator javascript

Tags: javascript

My project is littered with things like :

```
if(selectedDestination.modeOfTransport && selectedDestination.modeOfTransport.value === 'Driving'"){ 
  // Do something
}
```

Ideally I'd like to just have:

```
if(selectedDestination.modeOfTransport.value === 'Driving'")
```

and let it just be false if there's no 'modeOfTransport' property.

Comment: What is typo here `'Driving'"` ?

Comment: How will it know if modeOfTransport is undefined or not? You will have to check it somewhere.

Comment: This question is asked multiple times, from what I know there is no shorter solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key

Comment: Yeah it seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Doomenik There is a possible shorter solution. Create a wrapper for `selectedDestination` which returns a boolean for a given condition.

Comment: One could also use a custom function: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/pfy3s32j/ not really elegant though.

Answer (score 3):

something like that should suit:

```js
(selectedDestination.modeOfTransport || {}).value === 'Driving'

// or (to avoid prototype inheritance) 
(selectedDestination.modeOfTransport || Object.create(null)).value === 'Driving'
```

If you're using [`babel`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator), you can have a look at: [Nullish Coalescing for JavaScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing)

```js
selectedDestination.modeOfTransport?.value === 'Driving'
```

Tim's edit: Here is another option:

This is a common problem in JavaScript.  One cop out answer might be to define a variable which referenced the lengthy expression you want to avoid:

```
var mode = selectedDestination.modeOfTransport;
if (mode && mode.value === 'Driving') { 
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: While this would work, this is not the solution the OP requested. He wants to remove the `AND` gate as well as `XOR` most likely to keep his logical statements 'clean'.

Comment: If object is empty how will it have a 'value' key?

Comment: @MandeepJain it won't but you won't throw exception either looking for a property of object that doesn't exist

Comment: @MandeepJain It will just return `undefined`. If you tried to obtain another property from `.value` e.g. `.value.anothervalue` then it would throw.

Comment: @MandeepJain - that's the point :) - if selectedDestination.modeOfTransport is undefined then use `{}.value` - which is undefined, doesn't equal 'Driving' and doesn't result in an uncaught TypeError

Comment: ohh. got it. Thanks. Its dirty but effective

Comment: @MandeepJain `dirty` ?

Comment: I like the babel solution.  But is there any gotchas that are worth knowing?
I've already spotted one.  It works fine in the html template, but typescript complains if its in the ts file

Comment: @abyrne85 [Suggestion: "safe navigation operator", i.e. `x?.y`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16)